# Get a quote(Shipping methods estimation) not working in first time

Tags: module, shipping, extensions, quote, shipping-address

I am using `aheadworks iphone theme` in `Magento 1.7.0.0`. But the get a quote or calculate shipping section is not working in first time.

I have invested the issues and found that when I add product to cart its create two entries in `sales_flat_quote_address` table and then I calculate the shipping by entering `zipcode` in calculating shipping form.

The old entries deleted which was created during add to cart and it create new entries rather than updating the add to cart entities in sales_flat_quote_address.

But in case I calculate shipping second time its updating the entries second time.
I am using the core method `checkout/cart/estimatePost`.

Please help me in case you have any idea regarding this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Closing due to abandonment. Please provide an update including diagnostic approach of testing using out of box theme.

Comment: @benmarks The problem was solved by initializing cart object.

Comment: Will you please post that as an answer and self-accept?

Comment: @benmarks why not i will post my answer. Thanks